# hide NSMenu from a NSButton inside a custom view

Tags: xcode, cocoa, custom-view, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have a simple cocoa coredata statusbar application with Xcode 4.6.2.
Here in my `AppController.h` i have

```
@interface AppController : NSObject
@property NSStatusItem *statusItem;
@property IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
```

In my `AppController.m`:

```
@synthesize statusItem = statusItem;
@synthesize statusMenu = statusMenu;
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu;
}
```

then, in my `AppDelegate.m` there is a function:

```
#import "AppController.h"
-(IBAction)someAction:(id)sender{
    //code to do something
    AppController *x = [[AppController alloc]init];
    [x.statusMenu cancelTracking];
}
```

I want to close the menu via a button that performs an action inside a custom view of a NSMenuItem (from Connection Inspector->Outlets->view ctrl+drag to the button). I cannot select 2 different sent actions for a NSButton, so i have to close the menu declared in AppController class from the IBAction someAction that is in AppDelegate class. How to do it? The code i've posted doesn't work.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably doesn't work because you are initializing a second AppController.

You need a reference to your original AppController in AppDelegate. This can be achieved by using cocoa bindings. In your .XIB file, drag a new blue Object from your Object Library, set it to be a AppController class using the inspector, then control-drag into your AppDelegate header to create a binding. Use that reference and remove the `AppController *x = [[AppController alloc] init];`.

Comment: THANK YOU! But there's another thing to do, i have to insert "#import "AppController.h"" in AppDelegate.h, otherwise the IBOutlet will say "unknown type name". After this, in AppDelegate.m "[outletName.statusMenu cancelTracking];" and everything goes fine! Maybe you can edit your answer

Comment: and i can also delete the "#import "AppController.h" in AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] removeStatusItem:[GSAppDelegate alloc].statusMenu];
```